# dependencies lost: flutter pub get, dart pub get not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i really could need your help with a strange problem.

**Problem**
All dependencies are lost after i tried to reinstall them.
The 'pub get' cmd isnt working, either in flutter nor in dart.

**Story**
Ive created  my first App with flutter. While developing i tested it multiple times on different devices as well as the web application. At the end i tried to implement something which needed the provier package, i installed it and by accident added also 'provider listener' to the dependencies.

like this:
*dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
provider: ^6.0.1
provider_listener: ^1.1.1*

Later i decided to skip the new function and when i tried to cmd 'flutter build web' i received this message:

*Because narratives depends on provider_listener any which doesn't exist (could not find package provider_listener at https://pub.dev), version solving failed.*

So i tried to step by step to repair, clean and cache repair flutter and dart,
but the 'get' commands afterwards didnt work all for this reason:

*Resolving dependencies...
Because narratives depends on provider_listener any which doesn't exist (could not find package provider_listener at https://pub.dev), version solving failed.*

I also upgraded flutter and dart and run
'flutter doctor -v' and there was no problem detected.

Maybe iam dumb, but i really dont know how to proceed.
The app is connected to firebase and i dont want to set it up from scratch.
Do You maybe know a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that there was a socket error while trying to find the package **provider** on the pub.dev [The official package repository for Dart and Flutter apps.](https://pub.dev) repository. This error code typically suggests a network connectivity issue.

To troubleshoot this problem, you can follow similar steps as mentioned before:

```
1. Windows: ipconfig /flushdns

2. macOS and Linux: sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Actually it will **Flush** your **DNS cache** to eliminate any potential conflicts or outdated records. Open a command prompt/terminal and execute the appropriate above command for your operating system.

Also make sure the package is available and updated. After executing above commands reopen your ide and try again. If still the problem not solved then retry again and try with another internet connection.

Hope it'll work